# Multiple pdf from excel using check box

Tags: excel, vba

My challenge is to export multiple excel sheets by using checkbos. I have done the script as below, but it only works if one check box is selected. The row "Sheets(Array(tuloste)).Select" is giving error when both or none checkboxes are selected.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim nimi
Dim tarjousnumero
Dim polku
Dim sivut As String
Dim Liite1
Dim Liite2
If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Liite1 = "Palvelukuvaus"
Else
Liite1 = ""
End If
If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Liite2 = "Etävalvonta"
Else
Liite2 = ""
End If
tuloste = Liite1 & Liite2
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Range("I2").Activate
tarjousnumero = ActiveCell
nimi = InputBox("Anna tiedoston nimi", "Tallenna pdf muodossa", "Tarjous " & tarjousnumero)
polku = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Sheets("Kaupallinen tarjous").Select
Sheets(Array(tuloste)).Select
ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=polku & "\" & nimi & ".pdf", Quality:= _
xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _OpenAfterPublish:=False
Sheets("Kaupallinen tarjous").Select
UserForm2.Hide
End Sub
```

Comment: Obligatory [How to avoid select](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Your code is really hard to read without indentation and with this foreign names. I assume your problem is that no checkbox is selected, `tuloste` holds an empty string. What do you expect should happen when you issue `Sheets(Array("")).Select`? Or, with other words, what do you want to export in that case?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry -- below with less foreign word. I want to make a pdf_printout with have one fixed sheet (Kaupallinen tarjous) and attacments that I can select by chackboxes. The final pdf_printout can have 0 - 2 attachment at this moment. It may become more check boxes to select , so more dynamic code would be also appreciated. However for now I would be OK to have 0 - 2 attachments.
I solved the problem with having "" value for printout by using if-condition, but still struggling to select two checkboxes.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Dim file
Dim offernumber
Dim path
Dim pages As String
Dim printout As String
Dim Appendix1 As String
Dim Appendix2 As String


If CheckBox1.Value = True Then
Appendix1 = "Our services"
Else
Appendix1 = ""
End If

If CheckBox2.Value = True Then
Appendix2 = "Remote control"
Else
Appendix2 = ""
End If

printout = Appendix1 & Appendix2

ActiveWorkbook.Save
Range("I2").Activate
offernumber = ActiveCell
file = InputBox("Anna tiedoston file", "Tallenna pdf muodossa", "Tarjous " & 
offernumber)
path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
Sheets("Kaupallinen tarjous").Select

if printout="" then
Sheets(“Kaupallinen tarjous”).Select
else
Sheets(array(“Kaupallinen tarjous”, printout)).Select

ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=path & "\" & file & ".pdf", 
Quality:= _
    xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, _
    OpenAfterPublish:=False
Sheets("Kaupallinen tarjous").Select

UserForm2.Hide

End Sub
```